# How can I select a parent element, and all child divs that are not the first, as well as siblings of the parents and their children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Sorry for the poor title, I'm not sure how to word this issue.

I need some help writing a jQuery or javascript selector to get every childBlock that isn't the first. There are N number of parentBlock divs with at least one childBlock div child. We would like to change some of the labels for every subsequent child div after the first. What is the most efficient way to select these elements?

```
<div class="parentBlock">
    <div class="elementHead">
    </div>
    <div class="elementBody">
        <div class="childBlocks">
            <div class="childBlock" id='1'>
            </div>
            <div class="childBlock" id='2'>
            </div>
            <div class="childBlock" id='3'>
            </div>
            <div class="childBlock" id='4'>
            </div>
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
<div>
<div class="parentBlock">
    <div class="elementHead">
    </div>
    <div class="elementBody">
        <div class="childBlocks">
            <div class="childBlock" id='5'>
            </div>
            <div class="childBlock" id='6'>
            </div>
            <div class="childBlock" id='7'>
            </div>
            <div class="childBlock" id='8'>
            </div>
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

So in the example above, I would like to select childBlocks with an id of 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8. In my actual code, these div's don't have an id, they are just classed if that makes a difference at all.

I've tried:

`$(".parentBlock").find(".childBlock").not(':first').find('label.category ').text("Subcategory");`

But it seems to find the first childBlock on the screen, skip over it, then apply the text change to every other childBlock div that it finds.

Thoughts, or suggestions?

Comment: `$(".childBlock").not(':first')` doesn't do what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were very close. You want `first-child`, not `first`:

http://jsfiddle.net/pMYWS/

```
$(".parentBlock").find(".childBlock").not(':first-child').text("Subcategory");
```

(I am assuming that `label.category` is something present in your real code that isn't shown in this demo snippet)

Comment: That did it. Can't believe it was that small of a change. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

what about something like this?

```
$(".childBlocks:not(:first-child)") (do something here)
```